# Mysql Function Return group_concat

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql function for complex sql query that are being used through out the application. Its working fine but now i want to create a function that returns a group_concat. Its not working in this case. Its only return 1 id While it should return coma sepearted ids.

Here is a simple function

```
begin
declare orders text;

select b.orderids into orders from (SELECT group_concat(id) as orderids FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE type="general") as b;


return orders;
end
```

It is working if i execute this in mysql command and it returns a coma separated result but in function, it is only returning 1 orderid. Is there anything i am missing over here?

Sample tbt_orders:

id customer_id type total created_at

1  21 special 25 2017-01-25 09:10:44

2  24 general 48 2017-01-27 07:50:38

3  18 special 11 2017-01-27 09:17:08

4  2 general 66 2017-01-27 09:20:24

5  15 general 20 2017-01-27 09:26:59

Comment: You might want to provide some sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon, sample data added.

Comment: Check you function return type i think your return type will be integer

Comment: You are right. The problem was return type. It was INT